# Subquery condition from main query select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I want to do some subquery select where its condition is taken from main query select.

Here's my query :

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT MONTH(datetime_end) as B,
    (
        SELECT 
                SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, datetime_start, datetime_end))
            FROM 
                    [simrke].[trx_medical_ruang] MR,
                    [simrke].[trx_ruang] R
            WHERE
                MR.ruang_cd = R.ruang_cd AND 
                R.ruang_nm like 'BAKUNG%'   AND
                MONTH(datetime_end) = B
    )
FROM 
        [simrke].[trx_medical_ruang] M
ORDER BY B
    ;
```

Where sub query select condition `MONTH(datetime_end) = B` is from previous select but I got this error message :

> [Err] 42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'B'.

What is a proper way to point to first B select?

Comment: you can't reference a column alias in sub-query. Change to use the full expression `MONTH(M.datetime_end)` in the sub-query

Comment: thankyou, it is work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this : `MONTH(MR.datetime_end) = MONTH(M.datetime_end)`

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT MONTH(datetime_end) as B,
    (
        SELECT 
                SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, datetime_start, datetime_end))
            FROM 
                    [simrke].[trx_medical_ruang] MR,
                    [simrke].[trx_ruang] R
            WHERE
                MR.ruang_cd = R.ruang_cd AND 
                R.ruang_nm like 'BAKUNG%'   AND
                MONTH(MR.datetime_end) = MONTH(M.datetime_end)
    )
FROM 
        [simrke].[trx_medical_ruang] M
ORDER BY B
```

Answer (score 0):

is your query same as this ?

```
SELECT MONTH(datetime_end) as B,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, datetime_start, datetime_end))
FROM   [simrke].[trx_medical_ruang] MR
JOIN   [simrke].[trx_ruang] R
ON     MR.ruang_cd = R.ruang_cd 
WHERE  R.ruang_nm like 'BAKUNG%'   
GROUP BY MONTH(datetime_end)
```

Also try to use ANSI style of join

Answer (score 0):

As per Logical Processing Order of SELECT statement, you can not use B (i.e alias) in ORDER By clause instead you have to use what you have written in SELECT clause i.e MONTH(datetime_end) or sequence number (in numeric) of column which is 1 in your case.
In shot you can choose any of below to replace B from ORDER BY clause:

1. ORDER BY B = ORDER BY MONTH(datetime_end)
2. ORDER BY B = ORDER BY 1